# Image output from AVFoundation occupied only 1/4 of screen

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-image

I played around with `AVFoundation` try to apply filter to live video. I tried to apply filter to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, but the output occupied only 1/4 of the view.

[image]

Here are some of my related code

Capturing

```
let availableCameraDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    for device in availableCameraDevices as! [AVCaptureDevice] {
        if device.position == .Back {
            backCameraDevice = device
        } else if device.position == .Front {
            frontCameraDevice = device
        }
    }
```

Configure output

```
private func configureVideoOutput() {
    videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoOutput?.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_queue_create("sample buffer delegate", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL))
    if session.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)
    }
}
```

Get image

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer:
    CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    // Grab the pixelbuffer
    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!

    // create a CIImage from it, rotate it, and zero the origin
    var image = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
    image = image.imageByApplyingTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2)))
    let origin = image.extent.origin
    image = image.imageByApplyingTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-origin.x, -origin.y))


    self.manualDelegate?.cameraController(self, didOutputImage: image)
}
```

Render

```
func cameraController(cameraController: CameraController, didOutputImage image: CIImage) {
    if glContext != EAGLContext.currentContext() {
        EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(glContext)
    }

    let filteredImage = image.imageByApplyingFilter("CIColorControls", withInputParameters: [kCIInputSaturationKey: 0.0])

    var rect = view.bounds

    glView.bindDrawable()
    ciContext.drawImage(filteredImage, inRect: rect, fromRect: image.extent)
    glView.display()
}
```

I expected retina display and scale factor causing this, but don't sure where should I deal with this. I already set content scale factor to GLKView, but no luck.

```
private var glView: GLKView {
    // Set in storyboard
    return view as! GLKView
}

glView.contentScaleFactor = glView.bounds.size.width / UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the output `rect` used in the `drawImage` function:

```
ciContext.drawImage(filteredImage, inRect: rect, fromRect: image.extent)
```

The image's extent is in actual pixels, while the view's bounds are points, and are not adjusted by the contentScaleFactor to get pixels. Your device undoubtedly has a contentScaleFactor of `2.0`, thus it's 1/2 the size in each dimension.

Instead, set the rect as:

```
var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: glView.drawableWidth, 
                             height: glView.drawableHeight)
```

`drawableWidth` and `drawableHeight` return the dimension in pixels, accounting for the contentScaleFactor. See:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/glkit/glkview/1615591-drawablewidth

Also, there is no need to set glView's `contentScaleFactor`

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had the same problem which is fixed by applying the suggested change in this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which format are you setting before starting the capture? Are you sure that the video preview layer is filling the whole screen?
You have 2 ways to set resolution during an avcapture:

- Choose the `AVCaptureDeviceFormat` with the highest resolution, by looking through available capture format
- Using the `sessionPreset` property of you capture session. Doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2).

Comment: I didn't use `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` in this case, but OpenGL. For capturing I edit the post for that part.